# New line while doing Set in Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a below line in my batch script

```
SET /P _option= "Please select doc to be updated:       1 for Akeneo                2 for SFCC      3 for Contentful"
```

Which is displayed in CMD as show below

```
Please enter doc to be updated:     1 for Akeneo                2 for SFCC      3 for Contentful
```

How do i change it to add new line in between the statement i want to display it in CMD as below

```
Please select doc to be updated:        
1 for Akeneo                
2 for SFCC      
3 for Contentful
```

Comment: Why don't you use `echo` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see by the other answer it is very possible, but it seems like a bit of an overkill for you to want to do this where other options are available, like echo:

```
@echo off
echo Please select doc to be updated:        
echo 1 for Akeneo                
echo 2 for SFCC      
echo 3 for Contentful
set /p _option=
```

I would also advise you use `choice` for this instead of `set`

```
 @echo off
echo Please select doc to be updated:        
echo 1 for Akeneo                
echo 2 for SFCC      
echo 3 for Contentful
choice /c 123
goto :opt%errorlevel%

:opt3
echo you selected 3 for Contentful
goto :eof
:opt2
echo you selected 2 for SFCC
goto :eof
:opt1
echo you selected 1 for Akeneo
```

Answer (score 1):

You using the escape character, you can assign a newline to an environment variable and use it in the prompt string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@rem The empty lines after "set NL" are important
set NL=^


SET /P _option= "Please select doc to be updated:!NL!1 for Akeneo!NL!2 for SFCC!NL!3 for Contentful!NL!"

echo you picked !_option!
```

It's generally much cleaner to use the `choice` command though, since it prevents invalid input, and you can also avoid needing to put everything on one line:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo Please select doc to be updated:
echo 1 for Akeneo
echo 2 for SFCC
echo 3 for Contentful
choice /c 123
set _option=!errorlevel!

echo you picked !_option!
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do this is:

```
echo.
echo [1]Akkeno
echo.
echo[2]SFCC
echo.
echo[3]Contentful

set /p choice=Which document would you like to change?:
if %choice% == 1 goto ch1
if %choice% == 2 goto ch2
if %choice% == 3 goto ch3
```

and so on